# PayPal Pro : « OrderTotal (Amt) : Required parameter missing »

Tags: php, paypal

I get «  [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => OrderTotal (Amt) : Required parameter missing » in the response of my DoDirectPayment code, although this field does have a value.

This is so with PayPal but it works well using the exact same code with PayPal Sandbox. Here's my PayPal class :

[PayPal class](http://codepad.org/3USFbQ46)

And here's my DoDirectPayment code :

[DoDirectPayment code](http://codepad.org/fhBFcjU6)

Comment: Can you include the results of $request?

Comment: Here it is : Array ( [TIMESTAMP] => 2013-03-02T00:12:38Z [CORRELATIONID] => 34588b295e39a [ACK] => Failure [VERSION] => 94.0 [BUILD] => 5294323 [L_ERRORCODE0] => 81100 [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Missing Parameter [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => OrderTotal (Amt) : Required parameter missing [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error )

Comment: That's the response, we need the raw request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code looks okay, assuming `$_SESSION['total_price']` is set.  But something definitely appears to be preventing that AMT value from reaching PayPal.  Rather than arrays, can you do a back-to-back printout of the raw $request and $response strings? Lines 21 and 34.

Comment: You want to see the output of print_f($request) and print_f($response) right ? I'm not sure how to do that because the error only occurs with real PayPal so I would have to make a real payment. However it may be that the error doesn't occur systematically and my payment is processed successfully. What do you advise me to do?

Comment: Make a 'real' non-sandbox payment with a fake credit card number -- [getcreditcardnumbers.com](http://www.getcreditcardnumbers.com) or 'View Details' on a Buyer account in the sandbox.  You may get a decline, sure, but this would show AMT is passing correctly...

Comment: Thanks. I replaced $_SESSION['total_price'] by '3' and using your method I see that AMT is passing correctly (AMT=3&ITEMAMT=3 in $request, [AMT] => 3.00 in $response). This would indicate that there's a problem with $_SESSION['total_price']. But if it was so, payments should equally fail with PayPal Sandbox isn't it? Yet they work with Sandbox.

Comment: One would think, yes.. To dig deeper into that question I'd need to see the raw $result / $response for both sandbox and live with AMT = ''  (empty string)

(Perhaps the $_SESSION variable was actually set in the case of your successful sandbox tests?)

Comment: I made a payment online using fake CC number, both $request and $response contain all variables with correct values. Please note that the error message I mention in my original question « [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => OrderTotal (Amt) : Required parameter missing » comes from an automatic email generated by my website. Can spam bots be responsible?

Comment: Perhaps, or a finicky checkout flow...  So, my final answer: going forward, for the immediate future log to a file every single $request string and $response you get from PayPal.  You should x-out the CC and CSC numbers for your security and PCI compliance. Then you'll have some record of what's happening, should you encounter additional errors. You should also add an IF statement that checks to see if AMT is empty and prints out an error and asks the customer to try again -- rather than sending malformed payment requests on to PayPal.

Comment: I implemented some of your advice in your last comment and I'll implement the rest too. Thank you very much for your help Preston.